# Slide a UIView with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Upon button click, i want a `UIView` to slide down about `50%` of the screen. The slide should be animated. Following is what i have attempted so far:

```
- (IBAction)moveDownButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    _sliderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
                                                           , [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height*0.5)];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    _sliderView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,20);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: nothing happens. does not animate

Comment: I think you forget to add [self.view add subview : _sliderView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to insert the `_sliderView` in the view hierarchy:

```
[self.view addSubview: _sliderView];
```

or

```
[self.view.window addSubview: _sliderView];
```

then make a transform.

Maybe this what you want:

```
- (IBAction)moveDownButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    _sliderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
                                                           , 0)];

    [self.view.window addSubview: _sliderView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    _sliderView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,
                                  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
                                  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height*0.5);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```